# How to pass variable between classes

Tags: asp.net

In DAL class one ID is getting generated after doing ExecuteScalar
I want to pass this value through a variable from DAL class to another class. It’s for ASP.Net web form using c#

Trying to achieve it by using Session and Application variables but it’s not applicable here

Comment: Not enough information, is it a static class you want to pass the variable or any property or method to assign the value?

Comment: Why not use a return value?

Answer (score 0):

Gee, be it a simple "ID", a new row PK id as a reuslt of a insert?

Why would the fact of a class be any issue here?

```
 Classs ProjectInfo
    int ProjectID
    datatable whateer
```

So, I do a datbase insert, get some PK id

```
ProjectInfo.ProjectID = PKID

session["Project"] = ProjetInfo
```

Later on, in some page load, the say this:

```
 ProjectInfo = (clsProjectInfo)session["Project"]
```

Now, any and all "values" or "id" or whatever can be used.

So, say we want to pass that "ID" to anohter class, then this:

```
 SomeOtherClass.ID = ProjectInfo.ID
```

So, why would setting or passing some value from one class to another not work with a class tossed into session[]?

I see nothing here that suggests that "simple" code as you always written can't be used, and use of session[] to pass and persist such values from page to page or from code to code can't be used?

Be is a simple "id" you shove into session[], or shoving in a class into session? I don't see much of any difference here, and you are free to shove in values or a whole class into session, and passing and setting values between 2 classes is triavial, supported, and without any restrictions here that I can think of.

You have to explain why use of session[] not going to work here?

To be fair in MOST cases, when I pass a class via session to a target page? The FIRST thing I do in page load is transfer the session[] to viewstate. Assumign the class is small, the reason for this is that viewstate is per page, and session[] is per user.

However, what happens if the user opens the same page two times? Well, now session based for that class will apply to both pages, so I follow a design pattern using session to pass the class, but I then persist the class on that page with viewstate, since viewstate is per page, and thus code can continue to operate correctly based on that persisted class in viewstate which is "per page" as opposed to "per user".

If you don't follow the above design pattern, then use of session[] certainly can have some pit falls, since we have to assume that a user could have multiple copies of that one web page open, and thus one obviously  needs separation of code values when a web page may well be opened multiple times.

Now of course if that class is a "large" data object with lots of rows, then I don't recommend you place such objects into viewstate, and in fact I don't even recommend you place such objects into session[] either.

However, as a general rule, I see no reason nor limitations on passing values or even a class via session[], and you not provided any good reason for avoiding this approach, or in fact your claim that you can't use session[].

Until such time a good solid narrative is provided by you to avoid and not use session, then no solid reasons exist to avoid use of session.

Comment: Session is not coming up in DAL class it comes in aspx only

Comment: Well, when, and where are you using that class, and do you need it to persist - say for and during the operation of the one aspx page in question?  You on page load (!IsPostBack) create that class instance, have it pull the data you need, and then shove into session(), From that point on, then that class is persisted for the operation of that page. It really depends, since if you just doing a one time data pull, then in most cases you don't need the class persisted anyway, do you? So, the question then is where and when do you need that data?